# Mongo DB Duplicate Exception for non-duplicate records

Tags: json, mongodb, duplicates

I have the following record inserted into Mongo DB.

```
`{ "_id" : "531bbeae833b3d0977001597", "androidversioncode" : "16", "city" : "New York", "_t" : 1400921353 }`
```

I am trying to insert another record

```
`{"androidversioncode":"16","city":"Salvador","_t":1400930158}`
```

But it throws an Exception

> Error: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" :
>   "localhost:27017" , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   default.datarecords.$*id*  dup key: { : \"531bbeae833b3d0977001597\"
>   }" , "code" : 11000 , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 28 , "ok" : 1.0}

My code for inserting the record is here

```
while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {


  DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("datarecords");
  if (collection == null) {
    collection = db.createCollection("datarecords", null);
  }
  try {

     DBObject obj = (DBObject)JSON.parse(nextLine);

     collection.insert(obj);

   } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Could not create json object. " + nextLine + "Error: " + e);

   }

}
```

Is Mongo reusing the IDs ?

Comment: There isn't enough code there to really know what's going on, but you're inserting a record in with the same key. My best guess is you are setting the key to the same thing for two records by accident.

Comment: I am letting Mongo generate the keys on its own. The json data doesn't include a key.

Comment: The driver won't generate duplicate keys. The odds are astronomically low. So if this is reproducible it's almost certainly because the _id has been set the same thing over two inserts or set to an _id that's in the database. Can we see the code where the documents are created / the source that the documents are created from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo giving dup key error for fields with unique: false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445876/mongo-giving-dup-key-error-for-fields-with-unique-false)